# How to avoid bloated, deeply nested blocks when feature testing in RSpec/Cucumber?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, testing, rspec

Often when feature testing in RSpec/Cucumber I want to emulate a sequence of related procedural user actions. For instance, a user might sign in, then update profile, then take some other action on the site, then sign out, and so on...

In RSpec, an analogous feature test might look something like this:

```
describe "Step 1: Sign in" do
  before do
    # Capybara logic
  end

  describe "Step 2: Visit settings page" do
    before do
    end

    describe "Step 3: Update profile" do
      before do
        # More Capybara/etc...
      end

      describe "Step 4: Making a new post" do
        before do
          # ......
        end

        describe "Step 5: Viewing inbox" do
          before do
            # ...
            # More nested code etc, etc, etc...
          end
        end


      end
    end
  end
end
```

However, clearly this nesting very quickly gets out of control, especially when testing complex behavior on a site. Furthermore, the "before" blocks in the outermost nesting get run more times than then inner `before` blocks, unnecessarily slowing down the test suite.

**So, is there perhaps a more elegant way to handle this?** I'm able to clean things up slightly by using `shared_examples_for`, `it_behaves_like`, `shared_context`, `before(:all)`, helper methods, etc. But it seems rather awkward when all I want to do is run the tests procedurally without each test needing to run in isolation. In other words, I'm looking for a test DSL like this:

```
# Step 1:
test "Sign in" do
   visit "/sign_in"
   fill_in "whatever"

   # ...
end

# Step 2:
test "Update profile", after: "Sign in" do
   # Runs after "Sign in" sharing same context so variables and object states aren't reset
end
```

And yes I know in principle tests run in isolation, but let's be fair, doing so isn't always practical when each step in the test may rely on the outcome of a prior test.

Comment: The short answer is: don't nest. Treat each of your five steps as separate scenarios at the top level of "nesting". You can simply create the data or take the actions you need (signing in, updating settings) separately in each test. Extract methods. Reuse code and all that.

Comment: Yeah, defining modular methods to compose the behavior in each scenario context is pretty much what I've been doing. However, as I see it, the drawback is that there's a Small amount of repeated code in each scenario which hurts maintainability and causes specs to run a bit slower than they would otherwise need to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specs work great when grouped by requirements. It DRY's up the setup/teardown for each condition and makes them easy to scan when you know what the case is but don't know what the functionality would be.

For example:

```
describe "a logged in user" do
  before do
    # log in
  end

  describe "with 3 items" do
    before do
      # add 3 items
    end

    it "displays 3 items in the cart" do
    end
  end

  describe "with 0 items" do
    it "displays an empty cart" do
    end
  end
end
```

I don't think nesting specs works well for describing implementation (e.g. first do this, then do that). That seems to explode out really quickly